# SQL join one to many relationship - count number of votes per image?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Okay, so I have 2 tables:

```
images                           votes
----------------------------     --------------------
image_id |  name | square_id     vote_id |  image_id
----------------------------     --------------------
1         someImg    14          1            45  
2         newImg     3           2            18     
3         blandImg   76          3            1 
...                              ...
n                                n
```

This is a one to many relationship. Each image can have multiple votes, but a vote can only be related to one image. I'm trying to produce a join query which will show the image id, and the number of votes it has under a specified condition (say, based on `square_id`). Thus the query result would look similar to this:

```
query_result
----------------------
image_id |  vote_count
----------------------
18          46
26          32
20          18
...
55          1
```

But the best I can do is this:

```
query_result
----------------------
image_id |  vote_id
----------------------
18          46
18          45
18          127
26          66
26          43
55          1
```

See the problem? Each `image_id` is listed multiple times for each `vote_id` it has. This is the query which produces this:

```
SELECT images.image_id, votes.vote_id 
  FROM votes JOIN images ON images.image_id=votes.image_id
```

I just can't seem to create a `vote_count` column which is the sum of all the votes that image has. Is there some way that I can use the `count()` function to do so, that I'm simply not aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY images.image_id` and use `COUNT(votes.vote_id)`:

```
SELECT images.image_id, COUNT(votes.vote_id) AS cote_count
FROM votes 
JOIN images ON images.image_id=votes.image_id
GROUP BY images.image_id
```

Comment: Wow! This works... perfectly! Where's the magic here? Does the GROUP BY function take a 1-to-many relationship and turn it into a 1-to-1 relationship?

Comment: @Antilogical - Its not about the type of relation ship, its about the group, the `GROUP BY` here makes a list of distinct values of `image_id` then for the other column `vote_id` it uses an aggregate function with it, which is the `COUNT` which counts the votes for each grouped `image_id`.

Comment: @Antilogical - You're welcome any time :) You need to read more about the basics of sql queries, here is a perfect book: http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Queries-Mere-Mortals-Manipulation/dp/0321444434

Answer (score 2):

You generally need to use `GROUP BY` when using aggregates like `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT images.image_id, count(votes.vote_id) AS vote_count
  FROM votes 
  JOIN images ON images.image_id=votes.image_id
  GROUP BY images.image_id;
```

I'm not 100% clear on what you mean by

> and the number of votes it has under a specified condition (say, based
>   on `square_id`)"?

Your model seems to model `square_id` against image and can only be used as a `where` filter on `images`, not on a relationship between votes and images.

Comment: So it merges a 1 to many relationship into a 1 to 1? Can GROUP BY be used for more complex queries such as triple joins? (Where I may have a 1 to many to multi-many relationship)?

Comment: GROUP BY allows you to 'pin' one or more columns and then to use aggregates like `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, `MIN()` etc. If you can give an example of your relationship, I can update the answer.