# Handling Likes In A Commenting System SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'd like to build a basic commenting system on my website using Postgres. I am mostly a front end guy so I could use some help with determining if my solution is the proper way to go about handling likes.

Here are my tables, which I've pasted in from [dbdiagram.io](https://dbdiagram.io/). The syntax is a little different than you'd see in the SQL shell, but hopefully it should be easy to understand

```
Table comments {
  id integer [pk]
  user_id integer [ref: > users.id]
  text text
  num_likes integer
  created_at timestamp
}

Table users {
  id integer [pk]
  user_name varchar(25) [unique]
  email varchar(100)
}

Table likes {
  comment_id integer [ref: > comments.id]
  user_id integer [ref: > users.id]
}
```

Basically, I have a `likes` table that stores which comment it was placed on, and who the user was. My thought was, when someone likes a comment I would:

- Insert a new entry into the `likes` table.
- Update the `num_likes` value in the `comments` table

Then for deletions, I would:

- Delete the corresponding entry in the `likes` table.
- Decrement the `num_likes` value in the `comments` table.

Is this how someone good with this stuff would design it? If not, could you please explain how you would do it? It's going to be for a blog, so it doesn't need to be too over engineered and scale to Facebook size. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I personally feel a num_likes column is unneeded.  Just do a count(1) of the rows.  Some systems, like FaceBook, allow for differing reactions (like, laugh, sad, etc) so then you might put a where clause such as WHERE (reaction = 'like')

Comment: That's true. I didn't think of using the count function.

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571270/sql-join-one-to-many-relationship-count-number-of-votes-per-image  the 'votes' would correspond to your 'likes' and the images to your 'comments'